# Can't remove resin web server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, resin

From the day i installed resin in my ubuntu,i couldn't b able install any packages nor i could be able to remove it.I'm getting the similar error in both the cases

**`$sudo apt-get remove resin`**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  resin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 259061 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing resin ...
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/resin ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K10resin
   /etc/rc1.d/K10resin
   /etc/rc2.d/S90resin
   /etc/rc3.d/S90resin
   /etc/rc4.d/S90resin
   /etc/rc5.d/S90resin
   /etc/rc6.d/K10resin
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 446: /etc/init.d/resin: not found
invoke-rc.d: initscript resin, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing resin (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d: 446: /etc/init.d/resin: not found
invoke-rc.d: initscript resin, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 resin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can actually remove the Web Server but you can "not use it". I read somewhere that you can use Resin with Apache or other Web Server.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11330606) on the Ubuntu forums; it appears to match the question you're asking.  Try the answer contained there and see if that fixes your issue.